# How to avoid the dependencies of jar files to be included in the war build

Tags: maven-2

I have customized pom.xml in maven to build a war file, for which i am compiling few class files which in deed depends on some jar files. Which i have included them as dependencies.
The build was successful but end result puts me in trouble now i have those class files included in my war which i don't want it.

So can you please help me to get rid of jar getting included in lib folder of war.

Regards
Gnash-85

Answer (score 6):

You just have to change the "**scope**" of your dependencies in the Maven pom from "**compile**" (by default) to "**provided**". The "provided" libs won't be included in the final war file.

All options are listed on the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Benoit .. I was new to Maven.